# Not able to update a table script with a columnstore index (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, columnstore

When i try to update this statement getting error:

QUERY:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL]') AND name = N'INDX NAME')   
BEGIN  
--DROP INDEX [INDX] ON [dbo].[TBL]   
ALTER INDEX [INDEX] ON [dbo].[TBL] DISABLE  
END

UPDATE dbo.TBL  
SET Organization_Id= CASE Org_Id WHEN  @O_hf THEN  @HF  WHEN @O_hg THEN @HG ELSE    Orga_ID                                                                         END   
where Org_Id in (@O_hf,@O_hg)                                                       

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.change_tracking_tables   where object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL]'))      
ALTER TABLE dbo.TBL       
DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;       

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL]') AND name = N'INDX NAME')    
BEGIN     
ALTER INDEX [INDEX] ON [dbo].[TBL] REBUILD         
END
```

It will throw following error

> Msg 35330, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 UPDATE statement failed because
>   data cannot be updated in a table with a columnstore index. Consider
>   disabling the columnstore index before issuing the UPDATE statement,
>   then rebuilding the columnstore index after UPDATE is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will simply need to add a OPTION (RECOMPILE) clause to your statement, like this:

UPDATE dbo.TBL
SET Organization_Id= CASE Org_Id WHEN  @O_hf THEN  @HF  WHEN @O_hg THEN @HG ELSE    Orga_ID                                                                         END
where Org_Id in (@O_hf,@O_hg)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

This happens because when script is analysed before execution your table still has Nonclustered Columnstore, preventing any data manipulation.

I have more details on this in my blog post: http://www.nikoport.com/2016/03/07/columnstore-indexes-part-79-loading-data-into-non-updatable-nonclustered-columnstore/

Best regards,
Niko Neugebauer

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error immidiately after running the script, it means this happens because of SQL interpretation (compile error). 
If so, You need to use dynamic SQL for updating, something like below (you may need to use some cast if you get type mismatch error)

```
declare @txt varchar(max) = 
'UPDATE dbo.TBL  ' + 
'SET Organization_Id= CASE Org_Id WHEN  @O_hf THEN  @HF  WHEN @O_hg THEN @HG ELSE ' +  
'Orga_ID ' +
'END ' + 
'where Org_Id in (@O_hf,@O_hg) '
exec (@txt)
```

Comment: when i try to run this query, its not evaluating the existence of INDEX instead trying to update directly the table and its throwing an error as the INDEX didn't dropped in the previous step. 
                                                                
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL]') AND name = N'INDX_NAME')   
BEGIN  DROP INDEX [INDX] ON [dbo].[TBL]   END
UPDATE dbo.TBL  
SET Organization_Id= CASE Org_Id WHEN  O_hf THEN  HF  WHEN O_hg THEN HG ELSE Orga_ID END